# Can't make httpErrors to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, web-config, http-error

I've added the following to config file.

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom"
              existingResponse="Replace" 
              defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
    <clear/>
    <error statusCode="404"
           responseMode="ExecuteURL"
           path="http://google.se" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

However, it seems that I still get the default page with yellow background and the stack trace. I've tried commenting out the filter for error handling and adding/removing custom errors in system.web. (I'm trying the approach of httpErrors as suggested in [this great article](https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging).)

What am I missing? What more can I do to trouble-shoot it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it at an ASP.NET level like that :

```xml
<system.web>
    ...
    <customErrors mode="On">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="http://www.google.se"/>
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

If you really want to dot it at IIS level, you can like that :

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="http://www.google.fr" responseMode="Redirect"/>
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

When you want to redirect to an absolute URL, you must set the "responseMode" attribute to "Redirect", "ExecuteURL" is for dynamic served content, from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689487.aspx).

Comment: Not sure if it did - it was quite some time ago. However, knowing the stubborn me, if it wouldn't help, I'd be asking follow-ups, so I conclude it did help and that I got sloppy or stressed, hence missing your reminder. Apologies for that. You should've poked me more intensely. Answers are given for two reason only - be accepted or followed-up. I'm sorry. And *you.Future = new Anno{ happy = true }* to make you smile.